# Meaning of ってね in this context

Tags: meaning

While reading a light novel, I came upon this sentence. One man shook hands with another and then said.

> 「──[『革新』]{イノベート}せよ、幾瀬鳶雄。ってね。それに──兵藤一誠くんとヴァーリ・ルシファーも。悪の神どもの思惑を崩すために。そして、三十年後に訪れる絶対の絶望から生き残るために」

The usage of ってね confused me. As I understand, it is just というね, however I don't get what it means in this context. Is it "Something like this" or "That's how it is"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this って is a quotative particle and ね is for seeking agreement.

ってね is sometimes used to (jokingly) introduce a proverb/catchphrase/cliche; "You know, it is said that ...", "So people say ...".

> [逃げるが勝ち](https://jisho.org/search/%E9%80%83%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B%E3%81%8C%E5%8B%9D%E3%81%A1)、ってね。
>   (You know, they say) fleeing is winning (so I'm running).

This "革新せよ幾瀬鳶雄" is probably not a real established catchphrase, so this may be more like a joke "People might say 革新せよ幾瀬鳶雄!" The sentence looks like this person is flattering 鳶雄 with an imaginary grandiose catchphrase.

<sub>(FWIW, 幾瀬鳶雄 and イノベート don't sound similar at all to me)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

(Silly as this may sound, I could not think of any other explanations.)

We often add a 「ってね」、「なんてね」、「なんちゃって（ね）」, etc. immediately after making a pun.

These little phrases are the approximate equivalents of "Just kidding!", "Sike!", "Not!", etc. in English.

To answer your question from the context given (without knowing anything about the speaker's personality), I am inclined to think that the above is the case here as well.  (Does he joke a lot?)

So, what is the pun?  It is the pretty loose pun of:

『イノベート』せよ、 いくせとびお。= Inobeeto seyo, Ikuse Tobio.

**I**nob**eeto** **se**y**o**, **I**kus**e** **To**bi**o**.

なんちゃってね！

Comment: that is a hell of a "catch it if you can" pun, there!  0_0 I never would have caught that!

Comment: a similar English language pun might be "Don't peter out on us now, Peter!" ... groan....  -_-...

Comment: At first I thought about なんてね, but the conversation was serious (or, at least, it should have been).